# How to implement vertical sliding actionbar(like in the grofers app)

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, sliding, vertical-scrolling

I want to implement a layout in which the action bar is below an image. And, on sliding the screen up, the actionbar should also move up, along with the image. The action bar should then go to the topmost point of the screen and stop.

This is implemented in many apps like the grofers app.

I don't mind using an external library for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi ,Help me if you find solution for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469187/how-to-implement-these-screens-before-scrolling-after-scrolling-like-grofers-a?noredirect=1#comment50904847_31469187

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go Through this awesome Demo [Sample Code](https://github.com/vitovalov/TabbedCoordinatorLayout) using `Android Design Support Library` **Coordinator Layout**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this,It shows some of the important features in the new Design library:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement Here is sample code link.

[Please check this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a library same for your requirement. please find the [link](https://github.com/sacot41/SCViewPager/)
You have to customize from that library according to your need.

Comment: This is a broken link.

Comment: @Sid sorry please check the edited answer. Now link is working.